# Asignar un DefaultTableModel a un JTable (MVC)

Tags: java, mvc, java-swing, jframe

Tengo una clase destinada a manejar los eventos de los *JFrame* que tengo creados. Eso me permite jugar con ellos y no instanciar código en su estructura, cuestión de mantener una relación **Modelo, Vista, Controlador**.

Dentro del **frame principal** tengo un **JTable** y quisiera que cada vez que se iniciara el *frame* ese *JTable* tomara la estructura de un **DefaultTableModel** creado dentro de la clase de los eventos. Por cierto, no sé si crear una clase, solo de eventos y otra de funciones.

El código del de la clase manejadora de eventos es el siguiente:

```
public class ControladorEstudiante{

    EstudianteAdmin estAdmin= new EstudianteAdmin();
    EstudianteDAOImpl estDAO= new EstudianteDAOImpl();

    public ControladorEstudiante(EstudianteAdmin estAdmin, MostrarEstudiante estMostrar){
        this.estDAO= estDAO;
        this.estAdmin= estAdmin;
    }

    public void initEstudiante(){

    }

    public void ListarTabla(JTable tabla){
        DefaultTableModel modeloTabla= new DefaultTableModel();
        tabla.setModel(modeloTabla);

        modeloTabla.addColumn("NOMBRE");
        modeloTabla.addColumn("MATRICULA");
        modeloTabla.addColumn("NOTA");

        Object[] columna= new Object[3];

        int objGuardados= estDAO.extraerTodos().size();

        for (int i = 0; i < objGuardados; i++) {
            columna[0]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNombre();
            columna[1]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getMatricula();
            columna[2]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNota();

            modeloTabla.addRow(columna);
        }
    }
}
```

El siguiente es el código del *frame*:

```
package comm.estudiante.interfaz;

public class EstudianteAdmin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public EstudianteAdmin() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        menuFunciones = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        submenu_Modificar = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
        submenu_Eliminar = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
        submenu_EliminarTodos = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        txtBuscar_estudiante = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnAgr_estudiante = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablaEstudiante = new javax.swing.JTable();

        submenu_Modificar.setText("Modificar");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_Modificar);
        menuFunciones.add(jSeparator1);

        submenu_Eliminar.setText("Eliminar");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_Eliminar);
        menuFunciones.add(jSeparator2);

        submenu_EliminarTodos.setText("Eliminar todos");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_EliminarTodos);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnAgr_estudiante.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/comm/estudiante/imagenes/Nuevo Contacto.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        btnAgr_estudiante.setText("Crear Estudiante");

        tablaEstudiante = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex,int columnIndex){
                return false;
            }
        };
        tablaEstudiante.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        tablaEstudiante.setComponentPopupMenu(menuFunciones);
        tablaEstudiante.setFocusable(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablaEstudiante);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtBuscar_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnAgr_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtBuscar_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnAgr_estudiante))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 258, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EstudianteAdmin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAgr_estudiante;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu menuFunciones;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_Eliminar;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_EliminarTodos;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_Modificar;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablaEstudiante;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscar_estudiante;
    // End of variables declaration

    public javax.swing.JTextField getTxtBuscar_estudiante(){
        return txtBuscar_estudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JButton getBtnAgr_estudiante(){
        return btnAgr_estudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JTable getTablaEstudiante(){
        return tablaEstudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_Modificar(){
        return submenu_Modificar;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_Eliminar(){
        return submenu_Eliminar;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_EliminarTodos(){
        return submenu_EliminarTodos;
    }
}
```

Este es el código del método **extraerTodos()** de donde el **DefaultTableModel** llena la tabla:

```
public List<Estudiante> extraerTodos() {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmnt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM notas";
    List<Estudiante> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        con = dbcon.conectar();
        stmnt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            lista.add(new Estudiante(
                rs.getInt("id"),
                rs.getString("nombre"),
                rs.getString("matricula"),
                rs.getInt("nota")
            ));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

¿Cómo hacer para pasar el método **ListarTabla** como **parámetro del método constructor** del *frame principal* siguiendo el patrón del **MVC** y evitando instanciar código en una **Vista**?, o ¿Cómo hacer para **iniciar el frame y que la tabla tome ese DefaultTableModel**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo en vista que no se como utilizar **arrayList** te muestro una posible solución utilizando un **array**.

**Primero:** crear un método de tipo DefaultTableModel.

```
public DefaultTableModel consultarNotas() {

    String[] titulos = {"Id", "Nombre", "Matricula", "Nota"};
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
    String[] registros = new String[4];
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM notas";
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);
        while (rs.next()) {
            registros[0] = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id"));
            registros[1] = rs.getString("nombre");
            registros[2] = rs.getString("matricula");
            registros[3] = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("nota"));
            modelo.addRow(registros);
        }
        return modelo;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Segundo:** en el jFrame que contiene tu tabla crear la función para setearla.

```
public void cargarNotas(){
    nombreClase funciones = new nombreClase();
    try {            
        nombre_de_la_tabla.setModel(funciones.consultarNotas());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e,"Error al cargar las notas",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

**Tercero:** llamar a la función desde el constructor de tu clase

```
public nombreClase() {
    initComponents();
    cargarNotas();
}
```

con esto cada que ejecutes el jFrame la tabla automáticamente cargara el modelo.